# English translation of Garga Samhita on Krishna

Tags: translation-request, resource

Garga Samhita is written by sage Garga.

Is there any English translation for Garga Samhita available online?

Comment: There are two texts with the same name Garga Samhita. One is about life of Sri Krishna and other is a treatise on astrology. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Sri Krishna related.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the Sanskrit verse, word-to-word English translation with meaning by **Iskcon Vedic Media Library ebook** is available to get at [Radha.name - 6.7 MB (1970 pages) pdf](http://www.radha.name/sites/default/files/documents/1509/Sri%20Garga%20Samhita.pdf)  .The official site of Iskcon Vedic Media Library was [iskconmedia.com](http://iskconmedia.com) but it seems no longer hosted by team. you can take a look at [snap-shot](http://web.archive.org/web/20110808004829/http://www.iskconmedia.com/index.php).

The book contains following Khandas:

- Goloka-khanda
- Vrndavana-khanda
- Giriraja-khanda
- Madhurya-khanda
- Mathura-khanda
- Dvaraka-khanda
- Visvajit-khanda
- Balabhadra-khanda
- Vijnana-khanda
- Asvamedha-khanda