# What is the description of Radha's birth from Garga Samhita?

Tags: radha

I want to know the description of Radha's birth from Garga Samhita. It's described in [the 8th chapter of Canto 1 of Graga Samhita](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_1.8:_Description_of_Shri_Radhika%27s_Birth).

I've gone through the English translation of Garga Samhita as per suggested in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35351/277) but the translation of some verses are missing (only the first eight verses of Garga Samhita 1.8 are translated).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95234/discussion-on-question-by-hanugm-what-is-the-description-of-radhas-birth-from-g).

Comment: This will help 

Goswami, D. & Dasa, K. (2006). Chapter 8 - Description of Śrī Rādhikā’s Birth. 
In *Śrī Garga Saṁhitā*.  Rupanuga Vedic College. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/garga-samhita-english/d/doc1122885.html